# What counts as "Without a Weapon"?

Tags: fallout-shelter

One of the objectives you can get is to kill a certain number of a specific type of enemy "without a weapon".

I have had this challenge before, with Radroaches, which wasn't so bad. However generally, if one guy in the room had a weapon, it didn't count.

However now the challenge is Deathclaws.

[image: Kill Deathclaws without a weapon]

How am I meant to achieve this?

**Edit:** to clarify; would I have to remove weapons from all dwellers who might come in contact with the Deathclaws (which would likely be my entire vault), or does it only count as *killing* them (i.e. dealing the "final blow" so to speak) without a weapon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best strategy to go about killing Deathclaws without a weapons would be to equip your Dwellers that are fighting with the best armor you have. The mission to take them out is to take them out completely WITHOUT using a single weapon, which means, yes, you will have to smack 'em down without using your trusty alien gun.

I would suggest limiting your population down to exactly 59 dwellers before you are prepared to fight Deathclaws. Just as [ethanflips](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/269428/73976) said, this task is annoying, but you'll get through it. If you simply want to forget about it, don't forget that you can skip objectives once per day. Hope this helped and answered your full and complete question.

Comment: Why "exactly 59"? I'm assuming this is accounting for dwellers with certain max stats?

Comment: The reason for the number 59 is mainly because once you have reached 60 dwellers deathclaws will begin attacking your vault.

Comment: You can be attacked by deathclaws before having 60 dwellers. I've been attacked in the fifties before survival mode came out, and in the thirties on survival mode.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to put very good armor on the dwellers, so they don't die quickly and keep healing them. If anyone in a room has a weapon where a deathclaw is it won't count. That's how I did it. It may take more than one try which can be annoying, but it's not too hard...

Comment: does it matter if they pass through rooms where dwellers are using weapons?  Ideally they can be weakened by the time they reach the unarmed room.

Comment: @lI They can walk through rooms of people with weapons to weaken it.